# Renault Master spare wheel - best place to keep it

Tags: renault, van, spare-tire, campervan

I have a Renault Master 2003 MWB and I would like to put my spare tire outside the van.

Has anyone found a way to make it fit underneath? What parts did you use for this?

How about on the back door?

I know the PCD is 5x130 but I cannot find a decent carrier. Any tips?

Thank you.

Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested... This is what we ended up doing...

[image: custom made tyre bracket close up]
[image: custom made tyre bracket with whole door]
[image: custom made tyre bracket back]
[image: custom made tyre bracket with bike lock]

Comment: That's a very decent solution! We have the same need, could you tell me what make the mount piece is and a part number if possible? Thanks and well done.

Comment: @James - I commented on your answer that was not an answer and now my comment is gone... I made it myself using a thick stainless steel sheet - it was a bit of a mission (angle grinding thick stainless steel is a slow process). More importantly, I noticed that after a while the door started hanging down lower... I think the hinges are not strong enough in these vans to support the weight. I would not do this again... I would look for an alternative solution ie. under the chassis, under the floor, on the roof or even discard the spare altogether and carry one of these spray kits instead.

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia Sorry, my fault, I missed the option to move your comment along with James'. Thanks for reposting it!

Answer (score 0):

Leonardo  - thanks for posting this, I have movano and have been considering mounting on the rear door. I asked a door kit supplier Foundry 4 x 4, but have not as yet received a reply. The options are limited, as to mount under the van only allows just over 7" clearance, ok for a car but I wonder about insurance re modification, plus if you go off road, or a worn pot holed track.
Bill

Comment: Hey Bill, I didn't tell my insurance about it (not sure you need to). I must say though, that a few years later I am noticing that the door  has definitely been lowering down... Not sure, whether it is pot holes or just the weight of the wheel. In retrospect, I'd probably just get rid of the spare and look into using one of these foam kits new cars have...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at some conversions seemingly best option is to utilise the existing door hinges to support a wheel carrier. Such as wheeliams.co.uk, but looks like they do not now produce for older vans I think, I’ve dropped them an email to find out as we have a 2007 master that I want to hang the rear wheel on.